# CTGetSignalStrength error during validation

Tags: ios, xcode5

I'm trying to validate my IOS app through xCode 5, and it reports an issue: "The app references non-public symbols in Payload: CTGetSignalStrength."

I need to get the user's signal strength -- it's part of the service my app is giving.

This is my method:

```
+(int) getSignalStrength {
    int CTGetSignalStrength();
    int signalstrength = CTGetSignalStrength();    
    return signalstrength;
}
```

I am also calling `int CTGetSignalStrength();` in my `AppDelegate`.

This works, I get the signal strength fine. But now the validation reject. How should I go about it?

Comment: I don't believe that there is any way of getting the signal strength for an app that will be in the app store.

Comment: Seems like you're right, @Paulw11. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is simply not allowed by Apple. Here's their reply to my support ticket:

"Section 2.5 of the App Store Review Guidelines states "Apps that use non-public APIs will be rejected”.

CTGetSignalStrength is not a public API."